# Put a space inside array in two-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$role = isset($_POST['role'])?$_POST['role']:'';
$details = isset($_POST['details'])?$_POST['details']:'';
```

Output for arrays is:

```
Role: Array ( [0] => leader [1] => follower ) 
Details: Array ( [0] => lead [1] => follow )
```

I want to assign leader to lead and follower to follow. Then I put two arrays into one:

```
foreach( $role as $rl => $r ) 
{
  $array_test3[] = array($r, $details[$rl]);
}
```

Output for `print_r($array_test3)` is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => leader [1] => lead ) [1] => Array ( [0] => follower [1] => follow ) )
```

Then I tried to implode an array:

```
$test3 = implode('<|>',array_map('implode',$array_test3));
```

Output for `echo $test3.'<br/>';` is:

```
leaderlead<|>followerfollow
```

But I want is to get the following:

```
leader<|>lead<|>follower<|>follow
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implode the inner array using the same parameter:

```
$test3 = implode('<|>',array_map(function ($innerArray) {
   return implode("<|>",$innerArray);
},$array_test3));
```

Example at: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc6652ada1609ff62379eaac03c6e8cf9ca5a70b

Answer (score 1):

You could do something which was more a case of having a play and seeing how I could achieve this...

```
$role = ["leader","follower"];
$details = ["lead", "follow"];
$a1 = array_combine( $role, $details );
echo str_replace('=', '<|>', http_build_query($a1, '', '<|>'));
```